# How to cast a plain json object to typeorm entity

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

There is a transformer class called `PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer`, if I need to invoke its `transform` function, I have to pass in the `EntityMetadata` which requires connection, I think casting doesn’t really need connection. The current workaround is to do the following by just assign in constructor, but this won’t preserve the schema since the field keys are often changed.

```js
@Entity('myentities')
export class MyEntity {
  constructor(partial?: Partial<MyEntity>) {
    if (partial) {
      Object.assign(this, partial);
    }
  }
}

const entity = new MyEntity(json);
```

I am not sure if the casting can be done in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently attempting to work with `PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer()`.

I was able to use `getConnection()` to retrieve the `EntityMetadata[]`. I see that `getConnection.hasMetadata(*entity name*)` and `getConnection.getMetadata(*entity name*)` are available. If I understood your question correctly, I believe one of these will provide the `EntityMetadata` you are seeking.